# Deleting Django Rest Api Database

Tags: django-rest-framework

How do I delete the database I am using in DRF in command line, I want to reset the database to its initial state before I run my first migration. Is there a one line command in the terminal to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have probably phrased my question better. Just putting the answer here in case it is useful to anyone in the future. My database had some migrations that caused conflicts with the previous migrations for which I had to put default values but since the default values were specific to the front end of the user I needed to remove the existing database and start over. I did it by using the following commands in the terminal.

```
rm -f tmp.db db.sqlite3
rm -r myapp/migrations
python manage.py makemigrations myapp
python manage.py migrate
```

I would recommend going through the docs here it is pretty clearly outlined. 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#adding-information-to-our-model

Answer (score 0):

Never hesitate to run `python manage.py --help` to see existing options.
For your case you may use:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

This will bring you to the DB console, where you can use standard SQL, such as:

```
SHOW tables;
TRUNCATE table mytable;
DROP DATABASE mydb;
```

etc.

If you delete your DB, don't forget to create a new one and give your user priveleges to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the **db.sqlite3** file and all **migration files** inside /migrations folder.